# Spring-data-jdbc query with nullable collection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

While using spring-data-jdbc and postgresql to store and search data, I was not able to come up with a query inside @Query annotation which can cover collections which are nulls.
I mean the following simplified example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM dialects WHERE type = 'Artificial' AND (:languages IS NULL OR language IN (:languages))")
findAllByTypeAndLanguages(@Param("languages") List<String> languages);
```

When I call the repository with languages = null, I get an error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1

I didn't find an example in the documentation how this can be done.
Of course, I can handle null values in the java code and call repository methods accordingly, but in my case the search can have a few collections as input parameters and it will be a mess if I cover each case with separate query..

I tried to use also String arrays and it didn't work. However, it seems to work with List, so does it mean that spring-data-jdbc cannot work with collections of objects?

Answer (score 0):

The query should have next one body:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM dialects WHERE type = 'Artificial' AND ((:languages) IS NULL OR language IN (:languages))")
findAllByTypeAndLanguages(@Param("languages") List<String> languages);
```

Because when you have a collection of parameters that can be `NULL`, the query parameter also should be in `()`.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help as I expect that the collection itself can be null

Comment: what do you mean, if collection is null nothing will be returned instead of error that was previously

Comment: When I call findAllByTypeAndLanguages(null) I get this:
2023-09-09 10:29:01 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1

When the languages collection is not null, it works fine.
My idea is that if the collection is null, only type filter should be applied.

Comment: can you also try to execute this sql in native version ? In a `pgAdmin`  for example and try to pass there a param with null value.